# How close print socket if not Disconnect?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have web App and the App has thermal printer with static IP and port
Through service
My Code C# :

```
 IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
 socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
 //ReuseAddress : Allows the socket to be bound to an address that is already in use.
 socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);  

            socket.Connect(remoteEP);
            socket.SendTimeout = 2000;
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 2000; 
            socket.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            socket.Receive(data);
            //The shutdown function Disables sends and receives on a Socket.
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            //Closes the socket connection and allows reuse of the socket.
            socket.Disconnect(true);
            //Closes the Socket connection and releases all associated resources.
            socket.Close();
```

But Some Time Socket NOT Close and i cant create new socket with printer

So how i check if socket not close and if open how close it before create new socket ????

plz help me !!

Comment: What is the lowest time between closing and trying to re-open the socket?

Comment: short time it printer in restaurant

Comment: Assuming the printer has a well-behaved TCP implementation, your own should be well-behaved as well. That means graceful shutdown, which means not trying to close the socket until you've reached the end of the stream (i.e. receive returns 0 as the byte count). If you want to initiate the shutdown, call `Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`, but you need to wait for the other end to shutdown gracefully either way. Finally, don't call `Disconnect()` at all. It's not needed when the socket is managed correctly. `Shutdown()` and later `Close()` are all you need.